# I'm unable to have a responsive image in a modal

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying for a time to have a modal carousel with images brought from the database. After solving the issue with Javascript, I have a desing issue.

I'm unable to have a 'Download button' above the image. I tried with differents positions but no one fixed my problem.

[image]

As you can see, the download button is on the left of the image, and with `position: fixed` or `position: absolute` is positioned on the image, and I need it to be above, with the others positions it nothing happens.

Then, I have some other images like this one, that has the button on the correct position but I can´t click on it:

[image]

Or the image is occuping all the modal

[image]

All images have the same class and the same css properties:

```
.img-responsive {
    max-height: 100vh;
    margin: -113px 0;
    padding: 113px 0;
    max-width: 100vw;
}

.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 2%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    text-align: center;
}
.modal-content{
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

The modal is taken from [Bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/)

This is the Javascript here I create the list of images:

```
 if (z == 0) {
                        var div = document.createElement('div');
                        div.setAttribute('class', 'carousel-item active');
                        let btn = document.createElement('button');
                        btn.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-primary mt-3');
                        btn.textContent = "Descargar Imágen";
                        let im = document.createElement('i');
                        im.setAttribute('class', 'fa fa-download mx-2');
                        btn.appendChild(im);

                        div.appendChild(btn);
                        var img = document.createElement("img");
                        img.setAttribute('class', 'img-responsive img-fluid');
                        img.setAttribute('id', "img01")
                        div.appendChild(img);
                        img.setAttribute('src', result[z].path);
                        carusel.appendChild(div);
                        z++;
                    }
                    else {
                        var div = document.createElement('div');
                        div.setAttribute('class', 'carousel-item');
                        let btn = document.createElement('button');
                        btn.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-primary');
                        btn.textContent = "Descargar Imágen";
                        let im = document.createElement('i');
                        im.setAttribute('class', 'fa fa-download mx-2');
                        btn.appendChild(im);
                        div.appendChild(btn);
                        var img = document.createElement('img');
                        img.setAttribute('class', 'img-responsive img-fluid');
                        img.setAttribute('id', "img01")
                        div.appendChild(img);
                        img.setAttribute('src', result[z].path);
                        carusel.appendChild(div);
                        z++;
                    }
```

And this the html:

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" id="myModal">
                <div class="modal-dialog" id="modalDialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header" id="modalHeader">
                            <button type="button" class="btn-close" id="btnClose" onclick="CloseModal()" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                        </div>
                    <div class="modal-body px-0" data-bs-interval="false" id="@Model.First().getNumeroEntrega()">
                        <div id="C_@Model.First().getNumeroEntrega()" class="carousel slide carousel-dark" data-bs-interval="false">
                                <div id="Entrega_@Model.First().getNumeroEntrega()" class="carousel-inner" data-bs-interval="false">
                                    <!--Creacion del carousel con imagenes-->
                                    <!--Fin del carousel-->
                            <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#C_@Model.First().getNumeroEntrega()" data-bs-slide="prev">
                                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                                    </button>
                                    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#C_@Model.First().getNumeroEntrega()" data-bs-slide="next">
                                            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

```js
function GetImagenes(entrega, img){
    var z = 0;
    let modalHeader = document.getElementById("modalHeader");
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
    console.log(entrega);
    console.log(img);
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "GetPedidoImagenes",
        contentType: "aplication/json; Charset=utf-8",
        data: { 'entrega': entrega },
        async: true,
        success: function (result) {
            console.log("Longitud: " + result.length);
            if (result == 0) {
                alert("No hay Imagenes");
            }
            else {
                console.log(result);
                while (z < result.length) {
                    var carusel = document.getElementById("Entrega_" + entrega);
                    console.log(entrega, carusel)
                    if (z == 0) {
                        var div = document.createElement('div');
                        div.setAttribute('class', 'carousel-item active');
                        let btn = document.createElement('button');
                        btn.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-primary mt-3');
                        btn.textContent = "Descargar Imágen";
                        let im = document.createElement('i');
                        im.setAttribute('class', 'fa fa-download mx-2');
                        btn.appendChild(im);

                        div.appendChild(btn);
                        var img = document.createElement("img");
                        img.setAttribute('class', 'img-responsive img-fluid');
                        img.setAttribute('id', "img01")
                        div.appendChild(img);
                        img.setAttribute('src', result[z].path);
                        carusel.appendChild(div);
                        z++;
                    }
                    else {
                        var div = document.createElement('div');
                        div.setAttribute('class', 'carousel-item');
                        let btn = document.createElement('button');
                        btn.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-primary');
                        btn.textContent = "Descargar Imágen";
                        let im = document.createElement('i');
                        im.setAttribute('class', 'fa fa-download mx-2');
                        btn.appendChild(im);
                        div.appendChild(btn);
                        var img = document.createElement('img');
                        img.setAttribute('class', 'img-responsive img-fluid');
                        img.setAttribute('id', "img01")
                        div.appendChild(img);
                        img.setAttribute('src', result[z].path);
                        carusel.appendChild(div);
                        z++;
                    }
                }
                modal.style.display = "block";
            }
            console.log(result);
        }
    })
};

function CloseModal() {
    let modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

    modal.style.display = "none";
    modal.remove();
}
```

```css
.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 2%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    text-align: center;
}

#img01{
    max-width: 100vw;
}

.modal-dialog {
    display: table;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
    width: auto;
}

.modal-content{
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.columnaPedido {
    flex: 20%;
    max-width: 20%;
    padding: 0 4px;
    width: 100px;
}

.columnaPedido img{
    margin-top: 4px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
            <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" id="myModal">
                <div class="modal-dialog" id="modalDialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header" id="modalHeader">
                            <button type="button" class="btn-close" id="btnClose" onclick="CloseModal()" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                        </div>
                    <div class="modal-body px-0" data-bs-interval="false" id="1111">
                        <div id="C_1111" class="carousel slide carousel-dark" data-bs-interval="false">
                                <div id="Entrega_1111" class="carousel-inner" data-bs-interval="false">
                                    <!--Creacion del carousel con imagenes-->
                                    <!--Fin del carousel-->
                            <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#C_1111" data-bs-slide="prev">
                                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                                    </button>
                                    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#C_1111" data-bs-slide="next">
                                            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
       
<div class="columnaPedido mb-3">     
<img class="imgPedido" id="Imagen_1" src="https://www.naldo.com.ar/medias/-1-206944-HPK141M10S.jpg-515Wx515H?context=bWFzdGVyfHJvb3R8NDAxMjF8aW1hZ2UvanBlZ3xoYjcvaDllLzk2NDA2ODA2MjAwNjIuanBnfGE2MmIzMTBiZmNhN2QyYWJiMjM1ODYzM2QwYzFhMTI1Zjk0M2M2ZDYwZTU5MDk5NTU4ZmFiNTVlNjkwNDJkZmE" onclick="GetImagenes(1111,this)" data-img-mostrar="1" />


 <img class="imgPedido" id="Imagen_2" src="https://habitar.com.ar/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/image/600x600/e9c3970ab036de70892d86c6d221abfe/1/6/16236_-_nuevas-heladeras-gafa_01.jpg" onclick="GetImagenes(1111,this)" data-img-mostrar="2" />
</div>
```

Comment: Can you put this into a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)?

Comment: I don't know how to add the bootstap library in here...